# Execute ssh command without password?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, command-line-interface

I execute the following command:

```
ssh -l admin hostname command
```

Each time I execute it, I am asked to enter a password.  How can I automatically provide it with a password since I am going to put this in a bash script?

Comment: The standard method to accomplish something like this is to use [key-based authentication][http://serverfault.com/search?q=ssh+key+authentication].  Follow the link to see lots of SF questions on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. Make keys without a password: http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 2):

If ssh server not support publickey, use expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 0 0]
spawn ssh admin@$ipaddr
expect "Password:"
sleep 1
send "PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

And run

```
./script hostname
```