# canceled sftp password Requests?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, sftp

i write bash file contain sftp command ... but i have problem every time i execute bash sftp requests password of the remote server .. how i can give sftp password as default parameter ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i search a bout answer i found we can Automating SFTP using expect ... see the following link 
[Automating SFTP using expect](http://www.linux-bsd-central.com/index.php/content/view/26/)

Comment: So...like I suggested two hours before you awarded yourself the answer? Nice...

Answer (score 3):

SFTP uses SSH protocol. So, you can generate certificates using `ssh-keygen` and copy it to the remote server using `ssh-copy-id`. This way you can login without a password.

for more details, have a look at [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/187036/execute-ssh-command-without-password).

Answer (score 1):

Khaled's answer is probably your best option. You can also use [expect](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/) for this, good for instances where you are not allowed to install keys for one reason or another.